# How to empty value from input (ngModel)?

Tags: angular

I have this input :

```
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
```

Now i have function submit where i check if user enter valid password if not that i have in else this:

```
else{
       this.error = true;
       this.message = 'Wrong username or email!'
     }
```

And how can i in else add something like this to empty this field :

```
this.password = '';
```

Comment: What is the issue? `this.password=''` is not working?

Comment: i get an error Property password does not exist on type LoginComponent

Comment: you need to declare it in your component..https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the password inside  the component.

```
password: string;
```

Comment: thats it tnx :)